# How to display data statistic in C# for given code

Tags: c#

I have done this much work for my school project, now I am stuck on this portion of showing statistics, that how many tickets are pending, o resolve, etc. any example idea that how can I achieve this will be helpful thank you so much

- There should be a way to keep track of the number of tickets submitted, number of resolved tickets and number of open tickets, and a way to display those statistics to the console.
- There should be an option for the IT department to reopen the ticket. At this point the number of open tickets should be increased and the number of closed tickets should be reduced by 1. Ticket’s status should be changed to “Reopened”

There are two classes, one is ticket and one is program in C#, I have pasted here my code.

```
namespace projectcsharp
{
    internal class ticket
    {
        //*created a class*/   
        static int unqiue_id = 2000;
        int nid;
        string name;
        string staffid;
        string email;
        string issue;
        string status;

        //* constructor*/
        public ticket(string f_name, string f_staffid, string f_email, string f_issue, string f_status)
        {
            name = f_name;
            staffid = f_staffid;
            email = f_email;
            issue = f_issue;
            status = f_status;
            unqiue_id++;
            nid = unqiue_id;
        }

        //* constructor created without name and email, with "not specified"*/
        public ticket(string f_staffid, string f_issue, string f_status)
        {
            name = "Not Specified";
            staffid = f_staffid;
            email = "Not Specified";
            issue = f_issue;
            status = f_status;
            unqiue_id++;
            nid = unqiue_id;
        }

        //* stated a write line and read line console string*/
        public void show_info()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Details of Ticket: " + nid);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Staffid: " + staffid);
            Console.WriteLine("Email:" + email);
            Console.WriteLine("Issue: " + issue);
            Console.WriteLine("Status: " + status);
        }

        public int getID()
        {
            return nid;
        }

        public string Status
        {
            set
            {
                status = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace projectcsharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ticket obj1 = new ticket("roopa", "roo01", "roopa@hmail.com", "my p.c. is not working", "current");
            ticket obj2 = new ticket("hema", "hem02", "hema@hmail.com", "my mouse is not working", "current");
            ticket obj3 = new ticket("seema", "see03", "seema@hmail.com", "need new mouse", "current");
            ticket obj4 = new ticket("unk04", "password change", "current");
            // list<T> listname = new list<T>();
            List<ticket> tickets = new List<ticket>();
            List<ticket> resolved = new List<ticket>();

            tickets.Add(obj1);
            tickets.Add(obj2);
            tickets.Add(obj3);
            tickets.Add(obj4);

            int list_count = tickets.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < list_count; i++)
            {
                tickets[i].show_info();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("********current tickets********");

            for (int i = 0; i < list_count; i++)
            {
                ticket tempobj = tickets[i];

                if (tempobj.getID() == 2002)
                {
                    tempobj.Status = "resolved";
                    resolved.Add(tempobj);
                    tickets.RemoveAt(i);
                    list_count--;
                    i--;
                }

                if (tempobj.getID() == 2003)
                {
                    tempobj.Status = "resolved";
                    resolved.Add(tempobj);
                    tickets.RemoveAt(i);
                    list_count--;
                    i--;
                }
            }

            int list_count_1 = tickets.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < list_count_1; i++)
            {
                tickets[i].show_info();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("**********Updated Current tickets**********");

            int almuni_list_count = resolved.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < almuni_list_count; i++)
            {
                resolved[i].show_info();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("**********resolved tickets**********");

            for (int i = 0; i < almuni_list_count; i++)
            {
                ticket tempobj = resolved[i];

                if (tempobj.getID() == 2002)
                {
                    tempobj.Status = "Current";
                    tickets.Add(tempobj);
                    resolved.RemoveAt(i);
                    almuni_list_count--;
                    i--;
                }
            }

            int almuni_list_count_1 = resolved.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < almuni_list_count_1; i++)
            {
                resolved[i].show_info();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("**********Updated resolved tickets**********");

            int list_count_2 = tickets.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < list_count_2; i++)
            {
                tickets[i].show_info();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("**********Again Updated Current tickets**********");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after reading twice i still cannot understand what's the problem is.

Comment: hi thanks for your time, i need to develep a method where i can show how many tickets or entries are there for example: open tickets: 2/ closed tickets: 1/ reopened ticket:0 etc thanks for your help again

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to query and filter your lists. For example, given `List<ticket> tickets`, you could write something like this:

```cs
var resolved = tickets.Where(t => t.Status == "resolved");
```

This will retrieve the resolved tickets from your list. You can also use the `.Count` extension instead of `.Where` if you're only interested about the number of "resolved" tickets, as this will return an integer. You may use any custom filtering you want inside the lambda function of the LINQ methods to get different subsets of the original list.

As for reopening tickets, you shouldn't try to keep track of closed/open tickets in separate variables. Use LINQ instead to query this information when you need it. You can write a method `RepoenTicket()` in the ticket class that simply sets the `status` variable to `reopened` or `open`. It might be more elegant to write a `SetTicketState(string newState)` function that overrides the state with `newState`. Then you can use this function to open, close and reopen tickets. To improve it even further, you should use an enum to keep track of ticket status. For example:

```cs
public enum TicketStatus
{
    Open,
    Closed,
    Reopened
}

// ... inside the 'ticket' class, instead of "string status":
private TicketStatus status;
```

I would also recommend using a [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-6.0) instead of a static int to uniquely identify tickets. This will be guaranteed to be unique for each individual ticket, even between application restarts, in case you need to save the tickets to the hard drive, or a database.

Comment: hey, lazar thanks so much for ur time and efforts ...it will help people like me who are quite new to coding I will try all ur guidance